# NSNotificationCenter usage in viewDidAppear:

Tags: ios, notifications

I came across this code:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

    [nc removeObserver:self name:Hide object:nil];
    [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(MarkHide:) name:Hide object:nil];

}
```

Why it the observer first removed, and then added again?

Comment: I think a good person to ask this question is the one that wrote this code. I think it should prevent to have the controller registered to the same notification multiple times. If it's the right approach is - well - opinon-based.

Comment: In theory, showing that ViewController, then pressing Home, and showing it again should call twice `viewDidAppear:`. If you do not remove the observer, if you post the notification, `MarkHide:` will be triggered twice.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the same notification observer multiple times, you will receive the notification multiple times too.

`Observers` might be used during the life-cycle of a VC or just when the view is foreground or for a period of time etc..

`viewDidAppear` is called when the view is actually visible. During the lifecycle of a VC, `viewDidAppear` can be called multiple times (When a Modal VC -which was on top of the VC- dismissed and the view becomes visible again).

So in this case VC wants to listen the notifications while view is foreground. And since it is called multiple times, to be able to sure that observer is added just one time you have two options. Using a `boolean` variable - `isObserverAdded` (better way) to check if the observer is added already or remove and add the observer.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this idiom before: Someone wants an observer, but *only one* observer. If viewDidAppear is called for the first time, there is no observer so removing it has no effect, and an observer is added. If it is called for the second or more times, the old observer is removed and a new one added.

I very, very, very much prefer having a BOOL property that indicates whether the observer is added, then add the observer if I need an observer and the property is NO, and remove the observer if I don't want the observer and the property is YES (you can put that code nicely into the setter for the BOOL property).

The really nice solution is adding an extension to NSObject that does all this and stores the state using an associated object.